# Display issues after switching to KDE on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, display, kde, plasma

I recently changed desktop environments to KDE on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. However, there have been weird rendering glitches with certain applications. For instance, Cheese shows a nonsense output like you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPZXE.jpg). As you can see, it still takes a perfectly fine picture. Moreover, VSCode does not display correctly, and has odd glitches (can't think of another way to explain it). However, if I try to take a screenshot of it (VSCode or Cheese), usually the display crashes, resulting in a black screen. I can still switch to tty, and any music I have playing will continue to play, so it seems to be just the display. I have no clue where to begin with this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

I use KDE 5.44.0 and Plasma 5.12.9

Comment: Display issues often involve the video driver, so it would probably be useful to mention your video adapter (Intel, AMD, Nvidia) and driver (Nvidia proprietary or Nouveau, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is going on, you could try searching [bugs.kde.org](https://bugs.kde.org). Also make sure to test several more applications to confirm whether the problem is specific to these programs, or if there is some commonality between the affected problems.

If it turns out that the problem is specific to your version of Plasma, you might want to try the KDE Backports PPA. If your video driver seems to be at fault, consider upgrading it, or perhaps changing to an alternative driver. Actually, either of these may fix the problem even if you can't figure out what's going on.

Finally, your wording "I recently changed desktop environments to KDE on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation" makes me suspicious that something might have gone wrong due to this not being a clean installation of Kubuntu. Unfortunate as it may be, installing multiple desktop environments still seems to cause problems sometimes.